# Как сериализовать класс со свойством ImageBrush в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сериализовать класс в бинарник:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Item : ViewModelBase, ISerializable
    {
        //Other Property
        //...
        public ImageBrush Icon { get; set; }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        //Other Property
        //...
        info.AddValue("Icon", this.Icon);
    }

    protected Item(SerializationInfo si, StreamingContext sc)
    {
        //Other Property
        //...
        Icon = (ImageBrush)si.GetValue("Icon", typeof(ImageBrush));
    }
```

Проблема в том что класс `ImageBrush` нельзя сериализовывать. Можно пойти обходным путем и сериазовывать путь к картинке(png) а потом делать из него `ImageBrush`, но мне такое не подходит, потому что мне нужно что бы файл png тоже заносился в бинарник (надо что бы можно было десериализовывать весь класс только из бинарника). Как подобное можно реализовать? Не обезательно, хоть и предпочтительно, использавать именно `ImageBrush`, главное чтоб потом можно было сделать `ImageBrush` только из самого бинарника.

Comment: Вообще не лучшая идея сериализовать классы с логикой (VM и прочие), не поленитесь и создайте специальные классы для сериализации (которые не будут содержать логику), никаких проблем не останется, картинка в таком классе может быть представлена в виде массива байтов, например

Comment: @Андрей NOP Cпасибо так и сделал, я про сохранение картинки в масиве байтов. А логики в классе никакой и нет, кроме реализации `ISerializable`

Comment: Если ваш класс является VM, то это уже его одна из областей ответственности, поэтому для него достаточно, он не должен быть предназначен для сериализации, заведите другой класс. Паттерны не зря придумали

Comment: @Андрей NOP Я просто не заметил как сам напартачил написал ViewModelBase вместо ModelBase...(

Comment: Почитайте про DTO